# "Cauchy estimates" for an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n\ge0} f_n z^n$.
By the Cauchy integral we have that
$$|f^{(n)}(0)| \le \frac{n!}{R^n} \, \sup_{|z| = R} |(f(z)|.$$
This implies that if $f$ is analytic in a disk of radius $R$ then
$$ |f_n| \le M_R R^{-n} $$
where $M_R$ is the supremum of $f$ over the boundary of the disk.

What happens when $f$ is entire? I do understand that this means that $R$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily large, but is there any more precise statement?

Example: $f(z) = e^z = \sum_{n\ge0} f_n z^n= \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$.

Using Cauchy estimates we get that for all $R>0$ there exists $M_R$ such that
$$|f_n|\le M_R R^{-n}.$$

In reality we have something stronger that of course $f_n=\frac{1}{n!}$.

So my question: If $f$ is entire is there any hope to get a factorial in the estimates?

Comment: (1)The notation $f_n$ is really a bad choice. (2) If $f$ is entire, then the convergence radius of the power series is $\infty$. (3) In your second sentence, what is $R$?

Comment: I don't assume at the beginning that $f$ is analytic. $R$ is just a positive number.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I don't assume in the beginning that $f$ is entire, not analytic.

Comment: $f_n$ is just $\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. I am used to this notation.

Comment: I realised that we cannot expect a factorial, we just get that the coefficients decay super-exponentially, which can be much slower than factorial. However, if the function is of exponential type, then we get a factorial.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure to understand exactly your question, but Liouville’s theorem states that if an entire function $f$ is bounded, then it is constant.

And indeed here, with $f$ bounded you would have the $sup(|f(z)|)$ to be a positive real number divided by $R^n$, which goes to infinity and therefore $f^{(n)}(0)$ going to $0$. The thing to understand is therefore that if $f$ is not bounded, the so-called “max” goes to infinity and balances with the $R^n$, explaining why if $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: I do not assume a bound.

Comment: Notice that $M_R$ depends on $R$.

Comment: @tst The Cauchy integral formula estimate simply shows if $f$ is entire then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} R^n = 0$ for every $R$ ie. the Taylor series converges everywhere

Comment: Well, I understand that, I am wondering if there is any stronger implication or this is the most we can get.